# How can I have two Segmented Control working in the same UIViewController?l IOS SWIFT3

Tags: ios, swift3

In table view I can select multiple datasource by doing this
if(tableView == self.tableOutletName)

but when it comes to segment what should I do?
here I have 3 segmentControls

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentView1: SJFluidSegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentView2: SJFluidSegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentView3: SJFluidSegmentedControl!
```

how will I rewrite this function

```
func numberOfSegmentsInSegmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: SJFluidSegmentedControl) -> Int 

{

    return 6

}
```

so that I can give each segment control 6 4 and 3 segments respectively..

**Updated code here I am getting fatal error**

import Foundation
import UIKit

import SJFluidSegmentedControl

class  DataSource2: UIViewController, SJFluidSegmentedControlDataSource  {
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentView1: SJFluidSegmentedControl!

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentView2: SJFluidSegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentView3: SJFluidSegmentedControl!
func numberOfSegmentsInSegmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: SJFluidSegmentedControl) -> Int {


    switch segmentedControl {
    case segmentView1: return 6
    case segmentView2: return 4
    case segmentView3: return 3
    default: return 3
    }


}
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: SJFluidSegmentedControl,
                      titleForSegmentAtIndex index: Int) -> String? {
    if index == 0 {
        return "None".uppercased()
    } else if index == 1 {
        return "1 Hrs".uppercased()
    }
    else if index == 2 {
        return "2 Hrs".uppercased()
    }
    else if index == 3 {
        return "3 Hrs".uppercased()
    }
    else if index == 4 {
        return "12 Hrs".uppercased()
    }
    else if index == 5 {
        return "24 Hrs".uppercased()
    }
    return "0".uppercased()
}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: SJFluidSegmentedControl,
                      gradientColorsForSelectedSegmentAtIndex index: Int) -> [UIColor] {
    switch index {
    case 0:
        return [UIColor(red: 51 / 255.0, green: 149 / 255.0, blue: 182 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor(red: 97 / 255.0, green: 199 / 255.0, blue: 234 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    case 1:
        return [UIColor(red: 227 / 255.0, green: 206 / 255.0, blue: 160 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor(red: 225 / 255.0, green: 195 / 255.0, blue: 128 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    case 2:
        return [UIColor(red: 21 / 255.0, green: 94 / 255.0, blue: 119 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor(red: 9 / 255.0, green: 82 / 255.0, blue: 107 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    case 3:
        return [UIColor(red: 51 / 255.0, green: 149 / 255.0, blue: 182 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor(red: 97 / 255.0, green: 199 / 255.0, blue: 234 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    case 4:
        return [UIColor(red: 227 / 255.0, green: 206 / 255.0, blue: 160 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor(red: 225 / 255.0, green: 195 / 255.0, blue: 128 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    case 5:
        return [UIColor(red: 21 / 255.0, green: 94 / 255.0, blue: 119 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                UIColor(red: 9 / 255.0, green: 82 / 255.0, blue: 107 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]        default:
        break
    }
    return [.clear]
}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: SJFluidSegmentedControl,
                      gradientColorsForBounce bounce: SJFluidSegmentedControlBounce) -> [UIColor] {
    switch bounce {
    case .left:
        return [UIColor(red: 51 / 255.0, green: 149 / 255.0, blue: 182 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    case .right:
        return [UIColor(red: 9 / 255.0, green: 82 / 255.0, blue: 107 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    segmentView1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    segmentView1.layer.borderWidth = 2
    segmentView1.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    segmentView1.clipsToBounds = true

    segmentView2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    segmentView2.layer.borderWidth = 2
    segmentView2.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    segmentView2.clipsToBounds = true

    segmentView3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    segmentView3.layer.borderWidth = 2
    segmentView3.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    segmentView3.clipsToBounds = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

}

Comment: Where did the error occur? And the error message?

Comment: Set the View Controller as datasource for your segmented controls.

Comment: error occurred on   case segmentView1: return 6 and on   segmentsCount = dataSource.numberOfSegmentsInSegmentedControl(self).. I will paste the library code as well.. And yes all outlets are proper.. Library I used. https://github.com/sasojadrovski/SJFluidSegmentedControl/tree/master/SJFluidSegmentedControl/Classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always create a separate class for each segmented control datasource instead of pointing all the segmented control datasources to the same view controller. It would be cleaner than having switch/if/else statements all through your code.

Comment: Create class segmentView1DataSource inheriting from NSObject and the data source delegate protocol. Add protocol functions dealing just with segmentView1 data. Create instance of this class and set it as the datasource of segmentView1. Repeat this for segmentView2 and segmentView3. You will probably need to keep references to these datasource classes in the view controller as the delegate reference is probably weak.

Comment: ok adding separate datasource classes and a bit of rewriting the library helped me fix the problem.

Comment: @Spads how exactly do you call a function when you make a selection of a segment. I've been looking everywhere and cannot find it

Comment: nevermind I see that we have to use the `func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: SJFluidSegmentedControl, titleForSegmentAtIndex index: Int) -> String? {}` function. We must use the Delegate at the top of the class too

Answer (score 1):

You can `switch`:

```
switch segmentedControl {
    case segmentView1: return 6
    case segmentView2: return 4
    case segmentView3: return 3
    default: return 0
}
```

Remember to set `self` as the data source for all of the segmented controls!

Comment: this is what I did but I am getting fatal error.. datasource is given via storyboard.

Comment: http://oi63.tinypic.com/2r61ul1.jpg have uploaded the log to tinyPICs.. So it was working when I was returning a common count for all 3 segments.. As soon as I tried returning more than 1 count for each control it crashed.

Comment: @rollingZtoned This might be caused by not connecting the outlets correctly. Check if your outlets are connected. Also, on which line did the error occur? If it actually occurred in the `SJFluidSegmentedControl ` class, then this is likely a bug in the library.

Comment: error occurred on   case segmentView1: return 6 and on   segmentsCount = dataSource.numberOfSegmentsInSegmentedControl(self).. I will paste the library code as well.. And yes all outlets are proper.. Library I used. https://github.com/sasojadrovski/SJFluidSegmentedControl/tree/master/SJFluidSegmentedControl/Classes.. its working when I give a common return count.. but when I want to personalise based on each control it crashes..

Comment: @rollingZtoned based on the info you gave me, I am sure you did not connect the outlets correctly. Print `segmentView1`. If it is nil then you did not connect the outlets correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use switch/if statements in your datasource method like so:

```
func numberOfSegmentsInSegmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: SJFluidSegmentedControl) -> Int {
    switch segmentedControl {
    case segmentView1 : 
         return 6
    case segmentView2 : 
         return 4
    case segmentView3 :
         return 3
    default :
         return 0
    }
}
```